# Swift, Json Dictionary<String, AnyObject> send value to label

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2, label

I have a json who returns me a Dictionary. I can have values inside but I want to use one of this value to put in a label. I have no error but my label inside my view doesn't change.
Here code:

```
let url = "http://localhost:8888/connexion/"+login!+"/"+password!
        let urlString = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        let alreadyTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, let _ = response  where error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                print(json)
                print(json["3"] as! String)
                print(json["4"] as! String)
                print(json["5"] as! String)
                self.race_label.text = json["3"] as! String
                pa_label.text = json["5"] as! String
                name_label.text = json["4"] as! String
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        })

        alreadyTask.resume()

    }
```

And Here log:

```
["2": blabla12, "1": c@gmail.com, "3": orc, "4": test, "success": 1, "0": 5, "5": 100]
```

orc
test
100

So, I don't know why it doesn't work. Thank you !

Comment: do you have any log?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot ^^ now there is what returns me output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do UI related stuff on the main queue. `dataTaskWithRequest`s calls it's completion handler on a background queue.

To assure your calls are made on the main queue replace:

```
self.race_label.text = json["3"] as! String
pa_label.text = json["5"] as! String
name_label.text = json["4"] as! String
```

with:

**Swift 2:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.race_label.text = json["3"] as! String
    self.pa_label.text = json["5"] as! String
    self.name_label.text = json["4"] as! String
})
```

**Swift3:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.race_label.text = json["3"] as! String
    self.pa_label.text = json["5"] as! String
    self.name_label.text = json["4"] as! String
}
```

Comment: Xcode doesn't know dispatchQueue, and I don't understand what is it. This view is not the first I called. I have the firstviewcontroller with the connection, and Here I want to have the pseudo or race or PA inside ma DBB.

Comment: Are you using Swift3  ?

Comment: I'm using swift 2.1

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: You are perfect ! Thank you a lot !!